# How do you tell the Rails version inside of a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Up to Rails 2.3.8, there is a constant:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION   "2.3.8"
```

but Rails 3.0.0 doesn't have it.  Is there other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Rails.version`.

Most environment information that you might need from Rails should be accessible from that class.

[The documentation.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html)